# Playing audio in the background

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to add a functionality to a project I'm doing that as soon as the splash screen loads and the user is kicked to the next page I want and audio in the background throughout the app. What I've been seeing online are just audio player examples those ones need buttons and I don't want that

Comment: Be more specific, which platform you need to implement and why you need such functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flutter_sound package from the link.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound

On the class where you need to play the audio, import the flutter sound package. After that inside the initState method play the audio like below

```
@override
void initState() {
    FlutterSound flutterSound = FlutterSound();
    flutterSound.startPlayer(url); // here give the mp3 url like "audio1.mp3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'd try this out